# How to change UI using Media query depending on screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

**Need improved answer**

I have 5 sets of items.

1. Button
2. Text
3. Dropdown
4. Pagination
5. Icon

Now when screen size is large i.e. @media (min-width: 990px) {}

I want all items in a single row i.e.

```
[button][Text][Dropdown][Pagination][Icon]
```

When screen size is medium i.e. @media (max-width: 990px) {}

I want all items in 3 rows i.e.

```
[button]
[Text][Dropdown]
[Pagination][Icon]
```

When screen size is small i.e. @media (max-width: 575px) {}

I want all items in 4 rows i.e.

```
[button]
[Text]
[Dropdown]
[Pagination][Icon]
```

I have tried it in this code sandbox. Can anyone give me an improved answer for this?

Thanks.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 990px) {
  .items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top:30px;
  }
  .item23 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
  .items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top:30px;
  }
  .item23 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top:30px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 575px) {
  .items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top:30px;
  }
  .item23 {
     display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top:30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="items">
      <div class="item1">
         <button> button 1 </button>
         <button> button 2 </button>
         <button> button 3 </button>
         <button> button 4 </button>
         <button> button 5 </button>
      </div>
      <div class="item23">
         <div class="item2">
            <span> I am a Text! </span>
         </div>
         <div class="item3">
            <div class="btn-group">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               Choose letter <span class="caret"></span>
               </button>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><span>A</span></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
     <div class="item4">
       <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
        <ul class="pagination">
          <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
          <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
          <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
          <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
          <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
     </div>
     <div class="item5">
       <i class="bi bi-gear"></i>
     <div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Ref: https://codepen.io/belt-basya/pen/vYRXBzE

Comment: Why are items 2 and 3 combined into one parent element?

Comment: On a medium screen, we need text and dropdown in a single row; on a small screen, we need it in two separate lines. So to achieve this. Can we do it in a better way? If yes can you edit the sandbox? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may find that CSS grid gives you the sort of control you want.

Here's a simple snippet using grid-template-areas. You will want to investigate further to sort out the relative widths of the various items for your particular set-up of course.

```css
.items {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'Button Text Dropdown Pagination Icon';
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: Button;
  background: red;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: Text;
  background: green;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: Dropdown;
  background: blue;
}

.item4 {
  grid-area: Pagination;
  background: cyan;
}

.item5 {
  grid-area: Icon;
  background: yellow;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
  .items {
    grid-template-areas: 'Button Button' 'Text Dropdown' 'Pagination Icon';
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 575px) {
  .items {
    grid-template-areas: 'Button Button' 'Text Text' 'Dropdown Dropdown' 'Pagination Icon';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item1">
      <button> button 1 </button>
      <button> button 2 </button>
      <button> button 3 </button>
      <button> button 4 </button>
      <button> button 5 </button>
    </div>
    <div class="item2">
      <span> I am a Text! </span>
    </div>
    <div class="item3">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               Choose letter <span class="caret"></span>
               </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><span>A</span></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item4">
      <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
        <ul class="pagination">
          <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
          <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
          <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
          <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
          <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="item5">
      <i class="bi bi-gear">I</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```